# Validations bool

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, boolean, field

```
    **code to validate the UI design**

    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:tj_mobapp/palette.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
    import 'package:tj_mobapp/registration.dart';


class LoginSignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginSignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginSignupScreenState createState() => _LoginSignupScreenState();
}

class _LoginSignupScreenState extends State<LoginSignupScreen> {
      
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey =GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // void validate(){
  //   if(formkey.currentState.validate()){
  //     print("Validated");
  //   }
  // }
  bool isSignupScreen = true;
  bool isMale = true;
  bool isRememberMe = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.backgroundColor1,
```

body: Stack(
children: [
Positioned( // **This is the upper top image portion**
top: 0,
right: 0,
left: 0,
child: Container(
height: 300,
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
image: AssetImage("images/tjinfo.jpg"), fit:
BoxFit.fill)),
child: Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 20),
color: const Color(0xFF3b5999).withOpacity(.55),
child: Form(
key: formKey,
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
const SizedBox(
height: 15,
),
RichText(
text: TextSpan(
text: "Welcome to",
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 25,
//letterSpacing: 2,
color: Colors.white,
),
children: [
TextSpan(
text: isSignupScreen
? " Technology Junction,"
: " Login,",
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 25,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
color: Colors.white,
),
)
]),
),
const SizedBox(
height: 5,
),
Text(
isSignupScreen
? "Signup to Continue"
: "Signin to Continue",
style: const TextStyle(
letterSpacing: 1,
color: Colors.white,
),
)
],
),
),
),
// ),
),
),

```
        // Trick to add the shadow for the submit button
        buildBottomHalfContainer(true),
        //Main Container for Login and Signup

        AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
          curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
          top: isSignupScreen ? 200 : 230,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
            curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
            height: isSignupScreen ? 380 : 250,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      blurRadius: 15,
                      spreadRadius: 5),
                ]),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isSignupScreen = false;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "LOGIN",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: !isSignupScreen
                                      ? Palette.activeColor
                                      : Palette.textColor1),
                            ),
                            if (!isSignupScreen)
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                height: 2,
                                width: 55,
                                color: Colors.orange,
                              )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isSignupScreen = true;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "SIGNUP",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: isSignupScreen
                                        ? Palette.activeColor
                                        : Palette.textColor1),
                              ),
                              if (isSignupScreen)
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                  height: 2,
                                  width: 55,
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                )
                            ],
                          )),
                    ]),
                if (isSignupScreen) buildSignupSection(),
                if (!isSignupScreen) buildSigninSection(),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Trick to add the submit button
        buildBottomHalfContainer(false),
        // Bottom buttons
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(isSignupScreen ? "Or Signup with" : "Or Signin with"),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, top: 15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    buildTextButton(MaterialCommunityIcons.facebook, "Facebook",
                        Palette.facebookColor),
                    buildTextButton(MaterialCommunityIcons.google_plus,
                        "Google", Palette.googleColor),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Container buildSigninSection() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildTextField(emailController,Icons.mail_outline, "info@tj.com", false, true),
          buildTextField(passwordController,
              MaterialCommunityIcons.lock_outline, "**********", true, false),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Checkbox(
                    value: isRememberMe,
                    activeColor: Palette.textColor2,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isRememberMe = !isRememberMe;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  const Text("Remember me",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Palette.textColor1))
                ],
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("Forgot Password?",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Palette.textColor1)),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildSignupSection() {

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildTextField
            (nameController,MaterialCommunityIcons.account_outline, "User Name",
              false, false),
          buildTextField
            (emailController,MaterialCommunityIcons.email_outline, "email", false, true),
          buildTextField
            (passwordController,MaterialCommunityIcons.lock_outline, "password", true, false),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isMale = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: isMale
                                ? Palette.textColor2
                                : Colors.transparent,
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1,
                                color: isMale
                                    ? Colors.transparent
                                    : Palette.textColor1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child: Icon(
                          MaterialCommunityIcons.account_outline,
                          color: isMale ? Colors.white : Palette.iconColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Male",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Palette.textColor1),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isMale = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: isMale
                                ? Colors.transparent
                                : Palette.textColor2,
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1,
                                color: isMale
                                    ? Palette.textColor1
                                    : Colors.transparent),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child: Icon(
                          MaterialCommunityIcons.account_outline,
                          color: isMale ? Palette.iconColor : Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Female",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Palette.textColor1),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: const TextSpan(
                  text: "By pressing 'Submit' you agree to our ",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Palette.textColor2),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      //recognizer: ,
                      text: "term & conditions",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextButton buildTextButton(
      IconData icon, String title, Color backgroundColor) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Demo()),
        //   );
      },
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
          minimumSize: const Size(145, 40),
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          primary: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            title,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBottomHalfContainer(bool showShadow) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
      top: isSignupScreen ? 535 : 430,
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              boxShadow: [
                if (showShadow)
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
                    spreadRadius: 1.5,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                  )
              ]
          ),
          child: !showShadow
              ? Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.yellow],
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 1))

                  ]),
              child:IconButton(color:Colors.white,
                  onPressed:(){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const Registration()),
                    );
                  }, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward))
          )
              : const Center(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTextField(TextEditingController controller,
      IconData icon, String hintText, bool isPassword, bool isEmail) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: isPassword,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Palette.iconColor,
          ),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
          ),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
          ),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Palette.textColor1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code such that we can see what you did and help from there

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Am I right that you've built some form and now you're looking for a way to validate values inside text fields? If so - this manual should help (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) If I get your question wrong - share more details with us.

Comment: Hye there.
thankyou for responding.
i already shared a you tube video from which i have created a login and signup form.
but i don't understand the bool function.
as i want the same design with the validations.
like email incorrect password not entered or multi validation as Regex etc.
as the button was not defined in the video so i used icon button for summation and proceeding to next page

Comment: i am shareing the whole code here

Comment: how can i post the whole code as it is not allowing the characters here

Comment: if you cant understand the code here please see the link of youtube

Comment: if you dont understand the code do see the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4nEjn6TOZ4&t=1466s
 its the same code
thankyou.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i need to do varification of fields in this code.
i cant get it as i am unable to do it..i have tried may things but cant help out.
please help me i am stuck here and cand do further work.
i need to validate fields by lost focus or on submiting the button.

Comment: need help please